# hamming window for LPC

Tags: autocorrelation, window-functions, lpc

I am working on a library for generating LPC for speech synthesis.  I am currently using a hamming window for the spectral analysis which goes in 200ms blocks over the signal, and does the a-to-k conversion.

I have read some stuff online about a technique of overlapping these windows so it would process the signal in groups like [1-200, 150-350, 300-500, etc].

My question is:  How exactly is this done, and more important-- is there a benefit to overlapping the windows?  Will I get better results with my analysis?

Comment: What you are talking about here is called Welch's Method of spectral estimation.  If I remember correctly, 50% overlap is the most you would ever want to overlap (1-200, 100-300...), beyond 50% there is no additional benefit.

Comment: can you explain where the benefit comes from?  How does it work exactly, and I'm a little tripped up by the fact that frames 1-200 are for one frame of LPC data (ks, rms, pitch), so if I am generating my a-to-k based off of 100-300, how does that fit into one frame?  Am I taking an average?

Comment: I don't know anything about LPC, just spectral estimation.